# Parse non JSON to JSON

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have a file with data in it that I am needing to parse and store in a DB. Below, is an example of 2 entries in the file. I'm not quite sure what the structure is (although it looks to be ndJSON). I am trying to parse the data in to a JSON object in order to store it in a DB, but cannot seem to figure it out. Here is what I have so far

```
var ndjson = {
        "sequence-num": "0123456789",
        "version": "N1.4",
        "record-type": "R",
        "session-id": "197-30760303",
        "date": "2021-07-23 15:00:53",
        "passport-header": { "alg": "ES256", "ppt": "test", "typ": "passport", "x5u": "https://cr.com" },
        "passport-payload": { "attest": "A", "dest": { "tn": ["0123456789"] }, "iat": 0123456789, "orig": { "tn": "0123456789" }, "origid": "c699f78a-ebc6-11eb-bfd8-bec0bbc98888" },
        "identity-header": "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInBwdCI6InNoYWtlbiIsInR5cCI6InBhc3Nwb3J0IiwieDV1IjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9jci5zYW5zYXkuY29tL1RvdWNodG9uZV82ODNBIn0.eyJhdHRlc3QiOiJCIiwiZGVzdCI6eyJ0biI6WyIxMjUeyJhdHRlc3QiOiJCIiwiZGVzdCI6eyJ0biI6WyIxMj;info=<https://google.com/>;alg=ES256;ppt=\"test\""
    }
    {
        "sequence-num": "0123456788",
        "version": "N1.4",
        "record-type": "R",
        "session-id": "214-30760304",
        "date": "2021-07-23 15:00:53",
        "passport-header": { "alg": "ES256", "ppt": "test", "typ": "passport", "x5u": "https://cr.com" },
        "passport-payload": { "attest": "B", "dest": { "tn": ["0123456788"] }, "iat": 0123456788, "orig": { "tn": "0123456788" }, "origid": "c69d0588-ebc6-11eb-bfd8-bec0bbc98888" },
        "identity-header": "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInBwdCI6InNoYWtlbiIsInR5cCI6InBhc3Nwb3J0IiwieDV1IjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9jci5zYW5zYXkuY29tL1RvdWNodG9uZV82ODNBIn0.eyJhdHRlc3QiOiJCIiwiZGVzdCI6eyJ0biI6WyIxMjUeyJhdHRlc3QiOiJCIiwiZGVzdCI6eyJ0biI6WyIxMj;info=<https://google.com/>;alg=ES256;ppt=\"test\""
    };
 

    let result = ndjson.split(',').map(s => JSON.parse(s));
    console.log('The resulting array of items:');
    console.log(result); 

    console.log('Each item at a time:');

    for (o of result) {

        console.log("item:", o);

    }
```

When I run this, I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'` error on line 12 at the 2nd node of `"sequence-num": "0123456788",`.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: is `ndjson` supposed to be an array? If so, you are missing `[` and `]` and a `,` in the middle.

Comment: Does the actual file contain valid JSON? Because that is two objects behind each other, without a comma in between and without square brackets surrounding them. It's simply a JavaScript syntax error at this point. *If* the actual `ndjson` is a valid array, then there's no need to split or parse anything: https://jsfiddle.net/bo2h1684/

Comment: Storing objects in a DB can be done by either using a noSQL database or by turning the object into a string and storing it in a text column (using `JSON.stringify(some_obj)`)

Comment: @crashmstr I'm not sure if ndjson is supposed to have brackets or not. This is the data that is sent to me and I need to parse it in to JSON format by adding commas between each object and also adding brackets around the entire object.

Comment: @ChrisG this is the exact data that is sent to me in the file. I don't think it is valid JSON.

Comment: You mean everything in between `var ndjson =` and `;`? How exactly are you receiving this file? Who is sending it? Why do they send invalid JSON?

Comment: Whatever the *file* contents, your `var ndjson` you have here is not valid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: the json code structure is wrong (invalid), it makes the reader confused. is it a json array, json object or maybe a string of json?

Comment: @ChrisG yes, everything in the ndjson variable is what the file shows, except with more entries. The file has an extension of `.sti`. Like stated in the OP, I'm not sure what the structure is. I thought it could be ndJSON but I'm not 100% sure. I just need to take the data, as is, and create JSON from it.

Comment: If the file is neither JSON nor ndJSON then you probably need to look for lines that have a single `{` or `}` in them. However I'm getting really bad string composition vibes here; are you stuck with the file you're getting or can you tell somebody to fix the format? Because right now it's simply broken, and writing a specific parser might work but then suddenly just break. Obviously not a good way to move forward.

Comment: @ChrisG Unfortunately, I am stuck with this format. I was also thinking about writing a parser for this but I'm sure it will break down the road because of the syntax of the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually have `ndJSON`(newline-delimited JSON) then each line in the file is valid JSON, delimited by newlines. A simple file would look like this:

```
{"key1": "Value 1","key2": "Value 2","key3": "Value 3","key4": "Value 4"}
{"key1": "Value 5","key2": "Value 6","key3": "Value 7","key4": "Value 8"}
```

This differs from the formatted data you've posted here, and the difference is important since once you've formatted it, the valid JSON objects cannot simply be distinguished by the presence of newlines.

So, on the assumption that you do have valid ndJSON, in its original form, you can extract it by using `split()` on newLines and using `JSON.parse()` on the resulting array.

This snippet adds a little file handling to allow a file to be uploaded, but thereafter it uses `split()` and `JSON.parse()` to extract the data:

```js
"use strict";
    document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].addEventListener('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const selectedFile = document.getElementById('inputFile').files[0];
        let fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = function(e){
            let ndJSON = e.target.result;  // ndJSON extracted here
            let ndJSONLines = ndJSON.split('\n');
            // Process JSON objects here
            ndJSONLines.forEach(function(el){
                let obj = JSON.parse(el);
                Object.keys(obj).forEach(key=>{
                   console.log(`Key: ${key}, Value: ${obj[key]}`);
                });
            });
        }
        fr.readAsText(selectedFile)
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Parsing ndJSON</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="inputFile" id="inputFile">
    <input type="submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Output, based on the sample file above:

[image]

Comment: If ndJson has a new entry on each line, then the data structure isn't ndJson. How it is in the OP, is exactly how it is in the file.

Comment: @Rodney I took another look at this. It's easy enough to add leading and trailing brackets and insert a comma between the object to get a (nearly valid) JSON array. Even if you do that this element `"iat": 0123456789` won't validate.  The value should either be a string, or lose the leading `0`. A regular expression could probably fix this, but the file you're working with is clearly broken, and there's no telling what else might emerge. Go back to whoever provided it and get them to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do

```
const end_point_url = 'https://ipfs.io/ipfs/bafkqap33ejwgs3tfgerduitomrvhg33oebtg64tnmf2c4lroej6qu6zcnruw4zjsei5ce5dinfzsa2ltebqsa43fmnxw4zbanruw4zjcpufa';
let json = await fetch(end_point_url).
then( resp => resp.text() ).
then( buf => { // NDJSON format ...
  return buf.slice(0,-1).split('\n').map(JSON.parse);
}).
catch(console.error);
```